# Write streaming testcase in jest for download from remote url

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs, node-streams

I have the following API `/api/v1/download/:id`

**Usage:** http://localhost:3000/api/v1/download/client_app.zip

**Implementation:**

```
const express = require("express");
const axios = require("axios");
const { InternalServerError } = require("common-lib");

const router = express.Router();

router.get("/api/v1/download/:id",
    async (req, res, next) => {
        const { id } = req.params;
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(
                `${process.env.DOWNLOAD_URL}/artifacts/client_app/${id}`, {
                auth: {
                    username: process.env.USERNAME,
                    password: process.env.PASSWORD
                },
                responseType: "stream"
            });
            response.data.pipe(res);
        } catch (error) {
            return next(new InternalServerError(error.message));
        }
    });

module.exports = {
    downloadByIdRouter: router
}
```

A user will use the `/api/v1/download/:id` to download the .zip file from another remote server, the actual credentials and remote URL are hidden from the end-user.

The API is working as expected and I am able to download the file into my system.

The question is how to write the test for this particular streaming scenario in Jest.

```
describe("download by id test", () => {
    test("downloads the app, if requested properly", () => {
        // to do
    }, )
});
```

I checked this reference https://dev.to/cdanielsen/testing-streams-a-primer-3n6e. However, I am not exactly getting the approach.

I need guidance in writing the test for this particular scenario, comparatively new to Jest.

**Route import**

```
const express = require("express");

// Import routes
const { downloadByIdRouter } = require("./routes/download-byid");

const app = express();

// Use routes
app.use(downloadByIdRouter);

module.exports = {
    app
}
```

Then I import **app** in the test file and using the **supertest** library I make the API calls

**download.test.js**

```
const request = require("supertest");
const { app } = require("../../app");

describe("download by id test", () => {
    test.todo("starts the app download, if requested properly")
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you show the file where you define your routes?

Comment: I import the routes in app.js and then export it
const express = require("express");

// Import routes
const { getArtifactsRouter } = require("./routes/artifacts");
const { getArtifactsByIdRouter } = require("./routes/artifacts-byid");
const { downloadByIdRouter } = require("./routes/download-byid");

const app = express();

// Use routes
app.use(getArtifactsRouter);
app.use(getArtifactsByIdRouter);
app.use(downloadByIdRouter);

module.exports = {
    app
}

Comment: then require the app in the jest test file 

const { app } = require("../../app");

Comment: @Tyler2P any suggestion from your end